Firebase Sign in with LinkedIn through OIDC [firebase_auth/invalid-credential]
Setup

I have requested the API token in LinkedIn and activated "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect".
I have added the callback "https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler" with myproject being my actual project ID.
I have configured in Firebase linkedin as an OpenID Connect provider with Flow Code type.

My Code
 void signInWithLinkedin() async {
    OAuthProvider linkedInProvider = OAuthProvider('oidc.linkedin').setScopes([
      'openid',
      'profile',
      'email',
    ]);
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    }
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(linkedInProvider).then((result) {
      log('User ${result.user?.email} signed in with LinkedIn');
    }).catchError((error) {
      debugPrint('[FirebaseService:signInWithLinkedin] Error: $error');
    });
  }

Steps

I click the button that calls signInWithLinkedin()
I log in with linkedin in a web browser poped by the app
I authorize the application to use my account info.
Web returns to the callback link

Error

I/flutter (20848): [FirebaseService:signInWithLinkedin] Error: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, permissionsPolicies=[], headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Question
I need something else to configure? I've tested with the scopes above and without the scopes and nothing works.
